# Loc return column value instead of index value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which includes information about the real estate value of some assets and the expected time to sell in months:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'Asset_Id':[1,2,3]
               ,'REV':[150000.00,200000.00,250000.00]
               ,'TTS':[9,12,15]})
```

I am trying to translate this information into a cash flow statement, by creating a new zero-filled dataframe and replacing its values with a loc

```
df_CF = pd.DataFrame({'Income':[0.00 for n in (range(0,24))],
              'Months':range(0,24)})

df_CF.iloc[df_data.TTS,0] = df_data.REV
```

However, this code is replacing the 'Income' values with the values in the index position of the "Data" table, not the value that matches its TTS with the cash flow dataframe position. Since the "Data" table only contains 3 rows, this is returning an NaN.

In the "CF" dataframe, the expected return should be 150.000 in month 9, 200.000 in month 12, and 250.000 in month 15.

Comment: *"replacing its values with a loc"* makes almost no sense. For all us non-accountants, first please explain what 'TTS' stands for. Then, I think you mean *"insert the Revenue numbers in the corresponding months on the cashflow statement*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df_CF['Income']=df_CF['Months'].map(df_data.set_index('TTS')['REV']).fillna(df_CF['Months'])
print (df_CF)
      Income  Months
0        0.0       0
1        1.0       1
2        2.0       2
3        3.0       3
4        4.0       4
5        5.0       5
6        6.0       6
7        7.0       7
8        8.0       8
9   150000.0       9
10      10.0      10
11      11.0      11
12  200000.0      12
13      13.0      13
14      14.0      14
15  250000.0      15
16      16.0      16
17      17.0      17
18      18.0      18
19      19.0      19
20      20.0      20
21      21.0      21
22      22.0      22
23      23.0      23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df_CF.iloc[df_data.TTS,0] = df_data.REV.values
```

Comment: By using that an error appears:
"IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds", not exactly sure what it means...